# \cancel does not work with emf

Tags: png, open-office, cancel

In OOoLaTeX for OpenOffice, when I use `\cancel` in `.png` format, it works, but it does not work for `.emf` format. For the `.emf` case, it just puts a weird symbol on the letter. Any idea?

Edit 1:

In `.emf` format, `\cancel{a}` draws a diagonal, but with different symbols, not with just a line. It works well in `.png` format.

Edit 2: Works fine for LaTeX but not for OOoLaTeX.

Comment: `Any Idea` -- Hmm, unfortunately none! Please tell us something more informative about the problem. Thank you...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is relevant to your issue, but from browsing the [OOoLaTeX help forum](http://sourceforge.net/forum/forum.php?forum_id=503853), it appears that the set of `BaKoMa` fonts available from the OOoLaTeX website is incomplete, which causes errors with many symbols for .emf files, but not for .png files.  Apparently, the complete font files can be found [here](http://ooolatex.sourceforge.net/BakomaFonts_v2.tar.gz).

Comment: I installed `BaKoMa` but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: I guess that my answer was a bit of a shot in the dark.  Still, my guess would be that OOoLaTeX does not include (or does not include the newest version of) some package that the `cancel` package loads.